# I want to show the cropView to small size using Ucrop Library

Tags: java, android, ucrop

I tried to set **ucropView** size shows when begin crop start but the default aspect ratios does not give this result i want to show the **ucropView** like the above picture

```
    Uri sourceUri = PIDUtility.getImgUri(source);
    Uri desiUri = PIDUtility.getImgUri(des);
    UCrop.Options options = new UCrop.Options();
    options.setFreeStyleCropEnabled(true);
    options.setMaxScaleMultiplier((float) 50);
    options.setToolbarTitle(title);

     UCrop.of(sourceUri, desiUri)
            .withAspectRatio(1, 1)
            .withOptions(options)
            .start(this);
```

[image: I want result like this]

Answer (score 0):

Use below code. give aspect ratio `16:9` and `withmaxResultSize` property .Might it helps to you.

```
 UCrop.of(sourceUri, desiUri)
         .withAspectRatio(16, 9)
         .withMaxResultSize(maxWidth, maxHeight)
         .start(this);
```

Comment: i also tried this code is shown the cropview size  to full image size and its maximum size of the ratio

Comment: how much ratio you want to display?

Comment: i want show the cropview size like the above image.